# Reference Request: Application of Block Designs to Software Testing

Tags: reference-request

I've started looking at incidence structures and combinatorial designs (possible motivation: to upper-bound some structures in generalized self-assembly), and the Wikipedia article makes the following interesting-yet-unexplained statement: block designs have application to software testing.  (The Wikipedia page with the claim is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)).

My google-fu doesn't pick up a good reference for this application.  Can anyone give me a lead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have some software which includes a list of n variables s<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>,...,s<sub>n</sub> and suppose each of these variables are able to take on a range of values.  Now suppose you want to test the program for 2-way interactions, that is, you want to test the program runs correctly for every pair of variables s<sub>i</sub> and s<sub>j</sub> and every possible value that these variables can take.

To do this by a brute-force -- by processing each pair i and j one-by-one, then testing each allowable value of s<sub>i</sub> and s<sub>j</sub> (while picking the others arbitrarily) -- would require testing a enormous number of cases.

But, we can test for several 2-way interactions in a single test.  For example, if we have three variables s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub> and s<sub>3</sub>, and we test when s<sub>1</sub>=1, s<sub>2</sub>=2 and s<sub>3</sub>=0, then we have tested three possible 2-way interactions simultaneously.

We can design a test-suite for the program based on a [covering array](http://math.nist.gov/coveringarrays/coveringarray.html) -- the columns represent the variables and the rows represent the specific test to be performed (so fewer rows is better).  In a strength 2 covering array, within any two columns i and j, there exists every possible pair of the variables s<sub>i</sub> and s<sub>j</sub>.  There are higher strength covering arrays which can test for t-way interactions (but usually interactions are a result of only a few components).

Sets of mutually orthogonal Latin squares (and various other block designs) form particularly efficient covering arrays.

Answer (score 6):

See [Orthogonal Latin squares: an application of experiment design to compiler testing](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16591915454227907953).

Comment: Thanks, same comment as above - wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check these references:

[Cohen, D.M.;   Dalal, S.R.;   Parelius, J.;   Patton, G.C., The combinatorial design approach to automatic test generation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=536462)

[Cohen, D.M.;   Dalal, S.R.;   Fredman, M.L.;   Patton, G.C.;, The AETG system: an approach to testing based on combinatorial design](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=605761)